# Python Table - lists

Tags: python, list, tabular

Im designing a table in python, and im having a bit of trouble with the headers. This is the code I have now:

```
x = ["4","5","6","7"]
y = ["1","2","3","4"]
z = ["0","1","2","3"]

def Printtable():

       for row in zip(x,y,z):
       print '      '.join(row)

userinput = int(input("Input:"))

    if userinput == 1:
    Printtable().
```

I want the output to come out like:

```
Denary   Binary     Hex
0        0000       0
1        0001       1
2        0010       2
```

etc

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Answer (score 0):

`print '    '.join('xyz')` before your code? It's hard to say what do you want to get.